# Custom Field Accessibility permissions in Symfony2

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony

I`m developing a project in symfony2, where directors create a project and submit them to the agents. While creating the project the director has to have an option where he can use a checkbox next to the field, then only the agent can see the value of that field.
[image: like this]

Now the agent see both the fields as they are both checked.

This is my **Project** Document

```
class Project {
/** @MongoDB\Id */
 protected $id;

/** @MongoDB\String */
protected $name;
/** @MongoDB\EmbedOne(targetDocument="ProjectPermissions") */
protected $permissions;
}
```

**ProjectPermissions**

```
class ProjectPermissions {
 /** @MongoDB\Id */
  public $id;

  /** @MongoDB\Boolean */
  public $name_permission;

  /** @MongoDB\Boolean */
  public $type_permission;
  }
```

**Project Form**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) {
$builder->add('name', 'text')
      ->add('product_name','text')     
      ->add('permissions', new ProjectPermissionsType());
```

**ProjectPermissionsType**

```
class ProjectPermissionsType extends AbstractType {
  public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) {
    $notRequired = array('required'=>false);
    $builder
    ->add('name_permission','checkbox', $notRequired)
    ->add('type_permission','checkbox', $notRequired)
    }
 }
```

First, even though the form renders the checkboxes, <strike>it does not save it in the DB.</strike> Even if it is saved, how to handle from there?
Second, Am I in the correct direction? 
Third, Is there a bundle out there does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out theres no actual bundle that does field ACL. 
Moreover the above code works fine.